# onClick it update previous item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have 2 cards with btn wishlist. If user click btn wishlist, current id of card is selected and updated icon color. If user click same card again, wishlist is updated and color is removed. All is working until - when I click on first card, icon is updated, if I click to second card, first card is updated instead of second card.  If I am clicking only first card/same card, like toggle all is working, but if I click first card and then second card, it update first card instead second card.
I hope it is clear, when I click new card, last card is updated instead current card.
How to fix this issue? Thanks

```
const handleFavorite = async (id) => {
  console.log(id)  // show current id of card

  try {
    setLoadingCardId(id);

    const res = await axios.put('/api/event/makeFavorite', { id });
    setUser(res?.data.user);
   
    setLoadingCardId('');

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    setLoadingCardId('');
  } 
};


const checkWishList = (id) => {
  return !!user?.wishlist.includes(id);
};


  {
     loadingCardId === item._id ? (
     <PiSpinnerLight className="spinner-icon" />
      ) : (
     <BsFillBookmarkHeartFill
     onClick={() => handleFavorite(item._id)}
    className={`favoriteIcon ${checkWishList(item._id) ? 'text-danger' : 'text-dark' 
    }`}
   />
  )
}
```

backend code

```
const id = req.body.id;

     if (user?.wishlist.includes(id)) {

        // Remove from wishlist
     let updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
            $pull: { wishlist: id }
        });
        updateUser.save()

    } else {

        // Add to wishlist
     let updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
            $push: { wishlist: id }
        });
        updateUser.save()
    }
```

Comment: Hi pete, it is difficult to understand your problem just from your explanation and code posted. If you would like help, please consider recreating the frontend issue you're seeing in a CodeSandbox and updating your question with the link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new